# how can I put a picture in the center of the block?

Tags: html, css

Text is on center but image is not. How can i fix it?

```css
.advantage-first__block {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.advantage-first__block img {
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60px;
  height: 24px;
}

.advantage-information {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 129px;
  height: 76px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="advantage__info">
  <div class="advantage-first__block">
    <img class="advantage-src" src="images/advantage-car.png" alt="">
    <div class="advantage-information">
      Более 300 автомобилей в вашем распоряжении
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Text is on center but image is not. How can i fix it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLNcL.png)

Comment: add `text-align: center;` in `advantage-first__block `

Comment: <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    .advantage-first__block{
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    }
    .advantage-first__block img{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 24px;
    }
    .advantage-information{  

    width: 129px;
    height: 76px;
    text-align: center;

    }

    .emtzuh {
      position:absolute;
      left:50%;
      top:50%;
      transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    }

Comment: <!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div class="advantage__info">
                        <div class="advantage-first__block">
                            <img class="advantage-src emtzuh" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLNcL.png" alt="">
                            <div class="advantage-information emtzuh">
                                Более 300 автомобилей 
                                в вашем распоряжении
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `text-align: center;` in `advantage-first__block`

```css
.advantage-first__block{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: skyblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.advantage-first__block img{
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60px;
  height: 24px;
}
.advantage-information{  
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 129px;
  height: 76px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="advantage__info">
    <div class="advantage-first__block">
        <img class="advantage-src" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="">
        <div class="advantage-information">
            Более 300 автомобилей 
            в вашем распоряжении
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what about vertically centered

Comment: what do mean vertically centered?

Comment: centered on the y axis as well as the x

Comment: update my answer, using flexbox

Comment: nice I've always had trouble with it, forgot about flex...